# Picasso refreshing images in ListView each time I scroll

Tags: android, listview, picasso

I have a ListView which keeps refreshing images each time I scroll up and down

I am picking image urls from JSON which I supply to Picasso.

I am using Picasso to load images.

The total size of the images all together is 516kb, knowing that, I'm not thinking its a cache problem because image sizes are actually small.

Honestly, I have researched over this issue on S.O, and not seen any good solution yet.

Maybe the issue isn't related to Picasso, maybe my implementation is actually wrong. Please I need more knowledge on this.

This is my code below.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Genres> {

    ArrayList<Genres> movieList;
    TextView movietitle, moviecategory;

    LayoutInflater vi;
    int Resource;
    ViewHolder holder;

    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Genres> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
        movieList = objects;
        mContext = context;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ImageView imageView;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);

            holder.imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.movieimage);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(96, 128);
            holder.imageview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            holder.imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            holder.imageview.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
            holder.imageview.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

            holder.movietitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.movietitle);
            holder.moviecategory = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.moviecategory);

            v.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        Picasso.with(mContext)
        .load(movieList.get(position).getImage())
        .noFade()
        .into(holder.imageview);

        holder.movietitle.setText(movieList.get(position).getMoviename());
        holder.moviecategory.setText(movieList.get(position).getCategory());

        return v;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageview;
        public TextView movietitle;
        public TextView moviecategory;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you think that your image doesn't get cached you can set `setIndicatorsEnabled(true)` on your Picasso instance to see if it is getting loaded from the memoryCache. [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "refreshing"?

Comment: @david.mihola  By Refreshing i mean images disappearing as i scroll away from them, Images not in current window, and when i scroll back up, it disappears

Comment: It always attempts to request the images again each time i scroll

Comment: @mrtn When i used setIndicators and setLogging, I found out that the images are actually being cached. It shows me "completed from MEMORY"

Comment: So it does what it should do. ListView are creating their view items when they get visible, so when you scroll everytime the image is getting loaded from the cache. It is getting _lazy loaded_. Thats the best way to handle images in listviews. Or do you want to achieve something else?

Comment: No I dont want to achieve something else. thanks

Comment: I Later used Picasso .resize(96, 128) to resize my images directly which had a better optimization instead of Setting it in layout Params, and the issue was solved for now.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem that you have here is that you made your holder object an instance variable of of your adapter class, so in effect you have only a single view holder.

Try removing your instance variable declaration

```
LayoutInflater vi;
int Resource;
ViewHolder holder;    // remove or comment out this line 

private Context mContext;
```

and then make both the new view holder and the one returned by the `getTag()`

local variables.

So these two changes:

first:

```
if (v == null) {
   // holder = new ViewHolder();
   ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();  // replace above commented line with this line
   v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
```

and then in your else clause :

```
    } else {
    //    holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
          ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag(); // replace above commented line with this one.
    }
```

Now the holder stored by the layout will be different views rather than the one and only one that you currently have.

As a reference here is an adapter that I use with Picasso.  There are several differenced but I think the main thing is your use of a single instance variable for the viewHolder variable.

```
public class FollowedUsersListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserListItem> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<UserListItem> values;

    public FollowedUsersListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<UserListItem> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_layout, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView userNameView;
        public TextView lastPostView;
        public TextView postedTimeAgoView;
        public ImageView imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View followedUserView = convertView;
        if (followedUserView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            followedUserView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.followed_user_item_layout, parent, false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.userNameView = (TextView) followedUserView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
            viewHolder.lastPostView = (TextView) followedUserView.findViewById(R.id.last_post);
            viewHolder.postedTimeAgoView = (TextView) followedUserView.findViewById(R.id.posted_time_ago);
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) followedUserView.findViewById(R.id.user_icon);
            followedUserView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) followedUserView.getTag();
        holder.userNameView.setText(values.get(position).getName());
        holder.lastPostView.setText(values.get(position).getLastMicropost());
        holder.postedTimeAgoView.setText(values.get(position).getPostedTimeAgo());
        ImageView imageView = holder.imageView;
        String gravatarURL = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/"
                + values.get(position).getGravatarId();
        Picasso.with(context).load(gravatarURL).into(imageView);


        return followedUserView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this though, It didn't get any better. I Later used Picasso  .resize(96, 128) to resize my images directly which had a better optimization instead of Setting it in layout Params, and the issue was solved for now.